# AvalonEdit - Allowing user to scroll past end of the document

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, avalonedit

I'm using https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit library in my WPF project.
I ran into a problem, tho - users cannot scroll past the last line, so it's often hard to edit.
I want it to work like in Visual Studio Code:
[This function in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfyZt.png)

Could anyone at least point me to a solution?

I really don't have idea how to do this. I tried to use built-in methods, changing heights, I was searching everywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable this option:

`textEditor.Options.AllowScrollBelowDocument = true;`